# Как определять ближайшие маркеры?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

На карте есть  10 маркеров добавляющиеся через цикл

```
   var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
```

Также я добавляю еще один маркер при помощи 
Геокардинации

```
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: resultsMap,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
```

Так вот как мне определить какой из 10 маркеров наиболее близок к тому что я определил через геокординацию?Буду благодарен  Спасиьо за совет и помощ

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3

Comment: В апи есть специальная функция для вычисления дистанции между двумя точками. Пример по ссылке выше

Comment: @Grundy спасибо оьезательно посмтарю ты просто так ссылку не дашь ))я уверен там 80 % моего ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считать расстояния на сфероиде с помощью теоремы Пифагора, это, конечно, круто.

Нужно использовать функцию Google Maps API [`computeDistanceBetween(from:LatLng, to:LatLng, radius?:number)`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en-US#spherical)

Comment: у можно ссылки на документацию или ещё чтото по этой части?

Comment: @elik, поправил ссылку

Comment: @Grundy спасибо. Виноват, небрежно оформил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Посчитайте расстояния до каждого маркера и выберите наименьшее. Например:

```
var x1; //координата x Геокардинации
var y1; //координата y Геокардинации
var nearestMarkerNumber;

//массив с растояниями
var distances = locations.map(function(location) {
  var distance;
  var x2 = location[1];
  var y2 = location[2];
  distance = calcDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2);
  return distance;
});

//получаем номер ближайшего маркера
nearestMarkerNumber = calcMin(distances);


//функция возвращает номер ближайшего маркера
function calcMin(array){
  var min = array[0];
  var max = min;
  var i;
  var nearestMarkerNumber;
  for (i = 1; i < array.length; ++i) {
      if (array[i] > max) max = array[i];
      if (array[i] < min){
        min = array[i];
        nearestMarkerNumber = i-1;
      }
  }
  return nearestMarkerNumber;
}

//функция возвращает расстояние между маркерами с координатами (x1,y1) и (x2,y2) 
function calcDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  var distance;
  distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2 - x1),2) + Math.pow((y2 - y1),2));
  return distance;
}
```

Comment: спасибо Ты мне очень помог !Благодарю!!!!

Comment: не за что. Ответ KAGG Design считаю более правильным, но в относительно небольшой области сферическую поверхность можно аппроксимировать плоскостью и расстояния, вычисленные по теореме Пифагора, будут иметь не очень большую ошибку.

Comment: @Mikl согласен.