# Можно ли при помощи JavaScript обращаться к серверу Google Maps чтоб он возвращал расстояние между двумя городами?

Tags: javascript

К примеру, у меня есть такой код:

```js
var lat = 34.091393;
var lng = -117.239375;
var city = "San Fernando, CA, US";
var distance;
```

Мне нужно получить расстояние между городом, что записан в city и координатами (lat, lng). И чтобы это число (в милях) записалось в переменную distance. Как можно решить подобную задачу?

Comment: [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview)

Comment: когда то задавался таким вопросом, ответ нашел тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как определять ближайшие маркеры?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621894/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b)